# Absolute integrability and limits

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose that $h \in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ and define
$$
g(t) = \int_{t}^{\infty}h(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau. 
$$
Is it true that $\lim_{t\to\infty}g(t) = 0$? Seems 'obviously' true to me, but what's the formal way to argue it?

Comment: Dominated converge may be useful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first prove it with the assumption that $h\geq 0$. Consider the function $h_t(\tau) = h(\tau)\chi_{[0,t]}(\tau)$, where $\chi$ is the indicator function. Clearly $h_t\leq h$ and $h_t\to h$ pointwise as $t\to\infty$. Thus the dominated convergence theorem implies
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^t h(\tau)\,d\tau = \int_0^\infty h(\tau)\,d\tau.$$

Now, since $h\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ we can rearrange to find that
$$g(t) = \int_t^\infty h(\tau)\, d\tau = \int_0^\infty h(\tau)\,d\tau - \int_0^t h(\tau)\,d\tau.$$

Taking the limit $t\to\infty$ above proves the claim.

Now for general $h$ we can decompose it into positive and negative parts: $h =h^+ - h^-$ where $h^+,h^-\geq 0$ and both are $L^1$. Linearity of integration and limits now gives us the result in this case.

One word of caution: technically the dominated convergence theorem requires us to use a sequence of functions, rather than a continuously parameterized family like $h_t$. On the other hand, checking a limit $t\to\infty$ is equivalent to checking it for all sequences $t_n\to\infty$, so we can move between the two without issue.

Comment: I think I would summarize this as follows:  It is pretty obvious that, if you interpret the integral in the improper sense, then the statement is true. (You might well have already proved this for the improper Riemann integral).  So the issue is whether an integral $\int_0^\infty h(x)\,dx$ that exists in the Lebesgue sense must also exist in the improper sense.  This proof establishes that fact.  [The converse is true for nonnegative functions, but not in general.]